# Selected Link Color

Tags: css, hyperlink

I'm trying to have my links one color(grey) and when mouse hover it turns green and when clicked that green color STAYS. When a new link is clicked that link turns back to grey and the other STAYS green etc. I've got everything to work except the green to stay when one link is clicked. Anything I could do? Thanks!

```
<div id="navBar">
<font face="abeatbyKai">
<ul id="menu-list"> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="webpages/News.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="one">News</a></li> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="webpages/About Us.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="two">About Us</a></li> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="webpages/Gallery.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="three">Gallery</a></li> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="webpages/Affiliates.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="four">Affiliates</a></li> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="webpages/Biography.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="five">Biography</a></li> 
  <li><a class="menu_side" href="webpages/Contact.html" style="text-decoration: none" id="six">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</font>
</div>




#menu {
width: 275px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
overflow: auto;
background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
border-right-width: 7px;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-color: #000;
}
#navBar {
width: 225px;
height:260px;
left: 50px;
right: 0;
top:200px;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
overflow:hidden;
background:rgba(86,86,86,0);
font-size: 35px;
}
#menu-list {
padding:0; 
margin:0;

}
#menu-list li { 
list-style-type:none;
margin-bottom: 7px;
}

#menu-list a#one:link, a#two:link, a#three:link, a#four:link, a#five:link, a#six:link{
color: #5e5e5e;
}

#menu-list a#one:visited, a#two:visited, a#three:visited, a#four:visited, a#five:visited, a#six:visited {
color: #5e5e5e;
}

#menu-list a#one:active, a#two:active, a#three:active, a#four:active, a#five:active, a#six:active {
color: #07CB25;
}

#menu-list a#one:hover, a#two:hover, a#three:hover, a#four:hover, a#five:hover, a#six:hover{
color: #07CB25;
}

#main {
left: 275px;
right: 0;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
overflow: auto;
background: rgba(16,16,16,0.6);
}

#gallery1 {
width:475px;
left:250px;
top: 500px;
position: absolute;

}
a {
outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: When setting the style for several link states, there are some order rules: 1. `a:hover` MUST come after `a:link` and `a:visited` 2. `a:active` MUST come after `a:hover`

Comment: You can't accomplish what you want without either javascript/jquery or a page load inorder to add a class to your link to maintain the green.

Comment: @Scott I have put in jquery.js, I just didn't show the whole html

Comment: The same navbar is on every page?

Comment: @ChrisNash ya the navBar remains the same? want the full HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to style your links gray for link and visited, green for hover and active. Then, on each individual page, add a "current" class to the link that represents the current page. Style links in the current class green all the time.